Error: 'You have to add at least one recipient in the To field' when sending email from Case in Salesforce
I am encountering an issue when attempting to add the email address "testname-@outlook.jp" in the "To" field while sending an email from a case record. I receive the error message: "You have to add at least one recipient in the To field." This email address is valid, and I can save it in the email fields. However, the error occurs only when I try to send the email directly from the case.
Has anyone experienced this issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve it?

